# SBT won't run chisel tutorial... can't seem to find proper scala version

Tags: scala, sbt, chisel

I installed OpenJDK and then SBT on my Fedora 28 system.
SBT 1.2 comes from the bintray--sbt-rpm repository (the official one).
Both seem to work fine, and I can do basic scala projects.

Then I cloned the chisel-tutorial from the github chisel-tutorial site.
But when I go into the chisel-tutorial directory, SBT refuses to run at all, getting what appears to be an error about the scala version (which is well-nigh incomprehensible to me, but zillions of posts imply that scala version mismatch causes this message):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;`

My understanding is that sbt is supposed to find the right scala version, but in my case it clearly does NOT.

I have tried dozens of things, some hinted at by posts that refer to the above error message. But they never say *exactly* what to do, just say something like "your problem is scala version, and that should fix it".

Surely there are chisel users who know the answer, or sbt aficionadoes who do.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For me, Scala 2.12.6 with openjdk-1.8, sbt-1.1.1 seems to work.

Comment: What version of the OpenJDK are you using? Historically Scala and SBT have had issues with Java 9 and 10 (even though it is *supposed* to work).

Comment: Openjdk 1.8 is the version

Comment: Sbt 1.2 is the sbt version

Comment: Scala by itself works under sbt. The chisel-tutorial github repo does not.

Comment: Have you tried SBT 1.2.1 or 1.1.6?  I'm sorry I haven't had time to try to reproduce this on a VM yet

Comment: I will try 1.2.1 and 1.1.6 (manually overriding the repo)

Comment: I deleted the ivy2 cache, did sbt clean and update, and things seem to work now.

Comment: I'm not completely sure how I bypassed the problem I was having. At some point I will try to replicate the problem on another clean machine. But for now the various steps I tried, perhaps more than just the cache delete, clean and update, finally sorted things, and the tutorial is up and running for me.